# is there any command to import cv2 module

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

i am trying to import cv2 module in jupyter notebook but it shows the error"DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found".
please help me to solve my error

Comment: Please add more details. IE which OS are you using, which Python and Jupyter notebook version and a full dump of the error.

Comment: Run `%pip install opencv` in a cell in your notebook. Then try your code that includes the import.

Comment: We're going to need more information than this.

Comment: python version is 3.7.4

Comment: jupyter version is 6.0.1 windows edition is windows 8.1 pro N

Comment: i kindly need a n immediate hep and support

Comment: sir,i use pip install opencv command in anaconda prompt but t shows the error tht "NO MATCHING DISTRIBUTION FOUND FOR OPENCV"